# facebook comments not show

Tags: facebook, comments

I added Facebook Comment on my site.

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : appId,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', addedComment);
  };
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5appId=appId;
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

appId - number my application on facebook.
On page add next code:

```
echo "\n<div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=".the_permalink()." data-num-posts=\"7\" data-width=\"470\"></div>";
```

(I using Wordpress) Commentbox show on site, comments show in moderation tools, but on refresh page commentbox is empty.Why? 
(sorry for my English)

Comment: What is the outputted HTML of your PHP line there? Maybe change `the_permalink()` to `get_permalink()`.

Comment: My fault. But not resolve problem( Commentbox empty again.

Comment: Any messages in the browser's console? Have you tried "Inspect" on the commentbox? Possibly there is an error in the styling as well.